# Как присвоить label конкретному письму

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

В процессе переписки образовалась цепочка. В настройках ящика GMail цепочки отключены, но это никак не мешает им формироваться.

Методы `label.addToThread(thread)` и `label.addToThreads(threads)` работают по всей цепочке(цепочкам), а не по конкретному письму.

Как конкретному письму из цепочки присвоить label, а не всей цепочке, в которой присутствует данное письмо?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если пользователь отключает цепочки, то они не перестают действовать. В данном месте мотивы разработчиков более чем понятны. Вдруг, пользователь решит вернуть "все как было"? Возможно, есть еще какие-то причины.

В классе GmailApp концепция назначения ярлыка конкретному сообщению не реализована.

Для этих целей можно использовать [Advanced Google services - Gmail](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/gmail)

```
function setLabelToMessage() {
  // Get label by name 'test'
  var label = Gmail.Users.Labels.list('me').labels.filter(function (name, l) {
    return l.name === name;
  }.bind({}, 'test'))[0];

  // Get the first message from the search request
  var message = Gmail.Users.Messages.list('me', {
    q: 'subject:Проверка цепей'
  }).messages[0];

  // Set label to message
  Gmail.Users.Messages.modify({
    'addLabelIds': [label.id]
  }, 'me', message.id);
}
```